# Log-normal distribution: Why is this a density function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, statistics, random-variables

I want to prove that $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma x \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-\frac{\ln(x)^2}{2\sigma^2})$$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ is a density function, with $\sigma > 0$.

So what I have to prove is, this is our definition, is the following:

- $f$ is integrable and
- $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx =1$

But I have absolutely no idea how I could calculate that integral nor to show it exists, i.e. it is (improperly) Riemann integrable. Lebesgue integrable would also work here, but I don't see that either. WolframAlpha also cannot calculate this.

So how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried substituting $y=\ln(x)$?

Comment: Mathematica 12.1.1 is able to integrate the function from $0$ to $\infty$ with the assumption that $\sigma\gt0$.

Comment: Hint: [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Comment: You are going to find $\int_0^z f(x)\, dx = \Phi\left(\frac{\ln(z)}{\sigma}\right)$ where $\Phi(\,)$ is the CDF of a standard normal distribution.